# Angularjs interceptor doesn't add token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, header, request, interceptor

Hello I've created basic angularJS interceptor which should add token before every request. Token come from localforage and I'm sure it is there because I `console.log` it in interceptor and it is showing in browser console. When I try to log out it says 401 because token is not present on request althought interceptor looks good and it is not causing any error in console. I know that token is not present on request because I checked it in network tab in chrome console.

Code of interceptor:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('authInterceptorService', Factory);

    Factory.$inject = ['$q', '$injector', '$localForage'];

    function Factory ($q, $injector, $localForage) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {

                config.headers = config.headers || {};

                if(config.url.indexOf('v1') !== -1) {
                    $localForage.getItem('authorization')
                        .then(function (authData) {
                            if (authData) {
                                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                                console.log('theoretically i added token: ' + authData.token);
                                return config;
                            }
                            }, function () {
                                console.log("error with getting authorization localForage in interceptor");
                            }
                        );
                }

                return config;
            },
            responseError: function(rejection) {

                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    $localForage.clear().then(function() {
                        $rootScope.$emit('localForageUpdated');
                    });
                }

            }
        };
    }
})();
```

It doesn't add token to every request. `Console.log` which is just after line which should add token to every request is working as expected consoling correct value:

> theoretically i added token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwic2VjcmV0IjoiMmM2ZGNmNmYyNWZjOThjZDdiMjk4OTY2MDg2MTEzMjIifQ.5w-eCNnsWpkp-Ztpx8gpjeZ2AVNCRtbb1Pl3Iv3veLI

Why my interceptor doesn't add token to every request?

In previous version of my SPA i had `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.data.attributes.token;` inside success login function in login service and it was working correctly. Now when my SPA is bigger I decided to separate this from my login function.

I think that this issue can have something to do with `config.headers`. Maybe it should be `params` or something? Please quick help.

**EDIT**

I've done some more debbugin on my code and I found out something really interesting. When I addiotionaly `console.log(config)` I see that actually this token is within `config` object:

```
headers:
Accept:
"application/json, text/plain, */*"
Authorization:
"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwic2VjcmV0IjoiNzk5YThjYzkxYjI2NTdiYWI1ZGNiMzVkNWU3YzVlYmIifQ.RR00Y6LmDuSpePoYlm775AzhbTBIlO93OXnU9P1EHnw"
```

But Authorization header is still not present in network tab on request headers as you can see here:
[image: img]

**EDIT2**
Error here was that I was returning config before promise resolves as *charlietfl* mentioned in comment section below. So I tried to use `return` before `$localForage` and remove `return config;`. My SPA stops to render at all so I tried to use `$q` like this:

```
return {
    request: function(config) {

        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if(config.url.indexOf('v1') !== -1) {
            $localForage.getItem('authorization')
                .then(function (authData) {
                    if (authData) {
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                        console.log('theoretically i added token: ' + authData.token);
                        console.log(config);
                        deferred.resolve(config);
                    }
                    }, function () {
                        console.log("error with getting authorization localForage in interceptor");
                        deferred.resolve(config);
                    }
                );
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

but it also cause to stop render my SPA view. Generally it stops rendering when I delete `return config;`, why? It should work fine now..

I just had to add else to both condition in code sample above and use `deferred.resolve(config);` also there. Now everything is working.

Comment: promises are asynchronous...you are returning config before promise resolves and has a chance to modify it

Comment: I understand. So should I use $q.defer();?

Comment: return the existing promise when it is v1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean so where should I place return keyword? Before $localForage?

Comment: yes...when there is a `then()` it means it is  promise and inside that then you are already returning config

Comment: I added return before $localForage and now entire SPA doesn't render at all. Still no errors in browser console. Now code is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01f4b6b697b171c23b962a74c2ddfbb2

Comment: I added EDIT2 to my question please take a look.

Comment: But the resolve never occurs in `else` condition

Comment: Alright I had to add else to both condition and resolve also there. Now everything is working thank you charlietfl.